# Windows Server 2003 - Leave running when idle

Tags: iis, web, components, windows-server-2003, com+

I'm currently moving a website to a new server, whilst doing so i've noticed the option to set com+ application components running when idle.

This option is currently set to true on all components, but it sounds to me like there would be some sort of trade off (page load time vs strain on server).

Does anybody know what the realitve pros and cons are of these options?

Comment: You are upgrading from windows 2000?  You've noticed the COM+ applications created for web applications marked for high isolation have their idle timeout disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you are moving from Windows 2000 to Windows 2003.  On IIS6 Web sites (and applications defined within them) now use a dedicated concept of an Application Pool defined within IIS manager rather than use the original COM+ applications.

However in both cases there is an option to shutdown the process if it has been idle (that is no requests have been processed) for a period of time.

The upside is that the memory and other resources being occupied by the process is released.

The downside is the cost of spinning the process back up again and the restoring of any application level data whilst a user request is waiting.

For intranet applications or where the server is dedicated to serving a small set of specific sites enabling idle timeout is probably not a good idea.

Where you have dozens or hundreds of websites you probably host groups of these in the same application pool on IIS6 so again enabling idle timeout is probably ineffectual.

The only time I could see this being useful is a website that performs some heavy operations, is rarely used and installed on a server that has other duties.

Comment: Thanks very much, as it happens i'm simply moving from one 2003 server to another. Having not migrated a website before i'm simply trying to copy all the settings on the current websites to the new server, and this one setting just made me curious.

If what you say is correct, i wonder why Microsoft would choose to default the components to idle timeout?

Funnily enough, we do have a website on this server that sounds exactly like your last paragraph, i may experiment with it a little